# if conditions are not working while $(document).ready(function()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, if-statement, document-ready

I have tried the following code to display some divs.

```
<?
$uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri=explode('/',$uri);
$uri=$uri[4];
echo $uri;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var ty=<?=json_encode($uri);?>;
if(ty="gen")
{
  alert("gen");
}
else if(ty="cc")
{
  alert("cc");
}
else
{
  alert("not gen");
}
});
</script>
```

**$uri** value will be something like **/site/view-wall/type/gen/id/6**. The type variable can be changed to vo,cc,fr etc. If I changed the web address to www.example.com/site/view-wall/type/cc/id/6 I am getting alert "gen", not "cc".  Always I am getting alert "gen". The if conditions are not working. I couldn't figure out the simple if condition :(

Any help should be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, `==` or `===` are used to compare; you're using `=`, which sets the value of a variable. When you do this:

```
if(ty="gen")
{
  alert("gen");
}
```

That's equivalent to doing this:

```
ty = "gen";
if(ty) {
    alert("gen");
}
```

All non-empty strings are truthy, so your condition always succeeds.

To fix it, change the `=` in all of your conditions to `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the variable value, you have to use double equal == to compare